# Using 'splenda' in Vodka infusions. Serious headache!

Tags: flavor, vodka, hangover

Recently I posted a question ([here](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/6785/adding-flavor-to-vodka)) regarding adding flavor to vodka.  In my usual exuberance and non-scientific approach to matters I thought 'I know, to cut a few calories I will add Splenda'.  OK, the taste was OK, the orange and lemon peel that I steeped in the vodka gave the drink a nice, if not bitter taste.  I added splenda - and then experimented on myself (can't find anyone stupid enough to join me in these ventures!).  I drank the 'vodka' in the same manner (volume) as I would a standard vodka or gin.  Now, first morning after, the raging headache should have been sufficient - but looking for a more conclusive scientific result I tried the 'experiment' for a couple more nights, with the same results each following morning.  So, my question is:  Does adding an artificial sweetener to alcohol increase the chance of a hangover?

Comment: Can't find a tag for stupidity!

Comment: My comment, as I'm no expert on sweeteners, but am on headaches :D, many artificial sweeteners are vaso-constrictors,so that may be the issue.

Comment: Really, compared to alcohol, sugar isn't going to add all that many calories. Why don't you look up a recipe for limoncello?

Comment: @Eric Shain - Oh great now I feel really stupid, as I have one!

Comment: @Dorothy.  Hadn't thought of that - (this explains why no one else joins me in my 'experiments'!)  If I use my 'infusion' in something hot (cooked), will that reduce the effects of the vaso-constrictors.  (I've even managed not to come up with any snake jokes)

Comment: According to the internet, you can use Splenda In baking so I doubt heat will change it. Some people are just sensitive to certain artificial sweeteners. For you, I would suggest avoiding Splenda in the future, at least when you are consuming alcohol.

Comment: @Eric Shain.At least I don't have to avoid alcohol! I use a lot of splenda in the galley, but wondered what brilliant things you guys could come up with.

Comment: I suppose the high concentration of alcohol may have decomposed the sucralose compound in Splenda in some why that impacts your headaches. Perhaps this isn't happening when you consume the Splenda in food. In any case, I'm believing this batch is probably a loss for you.

Comment: How much splenda did you add?

Comment: @GdD.  Now that is a very good question!  The experiment was exactly scientific - thus all I can say is a 'splurge' of spenda!  Hope that helps!

Comment: If I use any sweeteners in anything, I get a headache. So I totally understand this. Don't ruin good drinks with sweeteners!

Comment: I mix my vodka with 50% water and then squeeze some Liquid Splenda in it. It comes out as a pretty nice and healthy drink.

Comment: @user14426 While I'm sure it is quite nice, calling this a "healthy" drink is stretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain people can have very individualistic headache triggers. For me it is second hand smoke. There are quite a few references on the internet tying Splenda to migraines so perhaps it so for you, at least in combination with alcohol. In any case, I'd pitch your experiment. Vodka typically has 65 calories per ounce. Sugar is about 111. However, you probably don't add that many ounces of sugar to your bottle of vodka so most of the calories will come from the ethanol. Some people substitute agave nectar which supposedly has a [lower glycemic index](http://www.allaboutagave.com/agave-vs-granular.php) than granulated sugar and may be healthier.

Comment: Many thanks for the agave nectar reference - that in itself is worth everything.

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 Indeed, agave nectar is intriguing. Here is a link to its use in cocktails instead of simple syrup: https://www.thespruce.com/what-is-agave-nectar-p2-760283

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 If you found my answer suitable, it would be great if you would accept it. Otherwise, feel free to request any improvements you would like.